# Java Socket client & server

Tags: java, file, sockets, client-server, printwriter

I tried the following code to send list of files and  directories, from server to client. the server is receiving from client but i don't know whether server is not sending back the result or client is not accepting it.

Server side:

```
package without.thread;


import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.rmi.Naming.list;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class SerTest {
  public static int reads,red;  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

          try
                  {
                      System.out.print("i m ready, call my client");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(18789);
                       while(true){ 
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        System.out.println(clientSocket+"1");
                       // outk=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true); 

                         BufferedReader bufferedReader;
       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you do `readLine()` on the client, while doing `outqw.write()` on the server. There is no end of line character in the string sent from server, so the client will never be able to finish the `readLine`. Do the outqw.println() or add `"\n"` to the end of whatever you're sending. That being said, it's very hard to navigate unformatted code with bunch of commented out stuff so the problem might be something else.

Comment: hey. brilliant and thanks a lot.. i spend 2 full days on this nd devoted my full time.. but didnt got the answer, thanks a lot. can u please provide me ur mailid. so that i could ask u for further doubt if any.. mine is amndhq@gmail.com....thanks a lot...

Answer (score -1):

Try manualy flushing the stream when sending something to the server/client.

Comment: thanks for ur help, (i got the output by using println)

Comment: The above method uses the same line of thinking. The the `"\n"` triggers the `.flush()` in the `.write()`. As you said you use `.println("something")` wich outputs `something \n`. This is the same as using `.write() +  .flush()` but you'd have manual control. Seems like  you are playing with some client/server code so i guessed you'd find this useful :)

Comment: *Non sequitur.* `\n` causes a `flush()`, if you construct the `PrintWriter` that way, but `flush()` doesn't cause a `\n`, and that's what the receiver is waiting for. Flush alone is not suffcient.